# Angular2: Implement Rx.Observable.retry() functionality

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have started learning angular 2. Trying to implement retry() functionality when my internet is down or server down. Currently when my internet is down API calls gets failed and loader is running indefinitely. So, I am trying to implement retry() functionality.

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemService } from './item.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'itemspage',
    templateUrl: 'items.component.html',
    providers: [ItemService]
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }
    items: string[] = [];
    loader: boolean = false;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.loader = true;
      this.itemService.loadItems()
        .subscribe((resp) => {
          this.items = resp.data;
          this.loader = false;
        });
    }  
}
```

**Service.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  loadItems() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:8080/****')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I found this article:  https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retry.md
But, don't know how to implement in my case. Help me.

Comment: You don't use retry anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where to use. I tried in component.ts but getting errors. So, I removed it.

Comment: It's an Observable operator. So you call it on an Observable. After the get(), or after the map(), or after the loadItems() call.

Answer (score 0):

```
loadItems() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:8080/****')
    .retry(5)                                   //<<<@@@@@ use it here
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**[read more here...](http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/)**